# My Java Recursive Function giving wrong output

Tags: java, recursion, formula

I am working on a Java Class. I have written all the methods correctly except for the 2 last methods which I'm struggling with.

My Question: What am I doing wrong in my specialRecursiveFunction to calculate the wrong output? 
...Or is the problem in my print method called reportOnValues that prints the numbers calculated in the method specialRecursiveFunction(int x)

```
  /* Write a recursive method named reportOnValues that will use each value in 
      a list to compute a recursive formula implemented in the method 
      specialRecursiveFunction. This method cannot contain any loop.
     */

    public static void reportOnValues(MyListOfInts M){
        if( M == null) {
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
        if(M != null) {
            System.out.println(specialRecursiveFunction(M.firstInt));
            reportOnValues(M.restOfTheInts);
        }
    }


    //My Recursive Function that defines x in a function of --> f(x) = {(1--> x=0) ; (1+f(x/2) --> x=even#) ; (1+f(x-1) --> x=odd#)}

    public static double specialRecursiveFunction(int x){
        if(x == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if ((x%2)==0) {
            return 1 + specialRecursiveFunction(x/2);
        }
        else {
            return 1 + specialRecursiveFunction(x-1);
        }
    }
```

> **Output I want is...**
>
> 3.0
>
> 7.0
>
> 4.0
>
> 5.0
>
> 5.0

**Output I get is...**

> 3.0
>
> 4.0
>
> 5.0
>
> 7.0
>
> 5.0

Comment: Code looks correct to me. What are the the inputs?

Comment: What were the inputs? And if your function is supposed to do what your comment says, it's doing the right thing.

Comment: @mwm314 Inputs are -- <System.out.println("Insert a number in a position of the new list:");
  LL=insertANumberIntoMyList(LL, 20, 3);
  printMyList(LL);    
  System.out.println();   

  System.out.println("Values obtained for the special recursive method:");
  reportOnValues(LL);

Comment: @mwm314 I apologize for the formatting in the last comment. Im totally stumped myself. My linked list contains the numbers (after manipulated by the remove and insert methods) 2 4 5 20 6

Comment: @JoshWilson ^^^ Same reply as above^^ I couldn't add 2 names in the comments. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: As others have stated the code actually does output what it should with the input you've provided. It also provides all the same values as in your expected output but in different order as if  the input should be 2, 20, 4, 5, 6 . Why do expect the output you're expecting? Why are you certain that the problem lies in these methods and not in e.g. insertANumberIntoMyList?